# TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a factory with code that gets calendar event data from the Google API. I have a directive with a link function that calls the factory service that runs the the function to get calendar event data from the API. When I call the service I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined. Can someone tell me why I am getting this error? When I log "gapi" in my console I can see the "auth" object property, but I still get undefined. Do I need to use some special code just for angular? Below is the code for my service and directive:

**Factory:**

```
var CLIENT_ID = '727304281402-2r6jn1l2jutllr07nc5ngba9omfqjand.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];

app.factory('getCalendar', ['$q', function($q){
return function checkAuth() {
    console.log("Getting Calendar Events");
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
    }, handleAuthResult);

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          loadCalendarApi();
          console.log("You are authorized");
        } else {
          console.log("Not authorized due to " + authResult.error);
        }
    }

    function loadCalendarApi() {

        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', listUpcomingEvents);
    }

    function listUpcomingEvents () {

        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId': 'magadesign.com_3337343339303832393534@resource.calendar.google.com',
            'orderBy': 'startTime',
            'singleEvents': true,
            'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
            'showDeleted': false,
            'maxResults': 3
        });

        request.then(function(response){

            var results = response.result.items;

            if(results === 0 ) {
                console.log('There are no events');
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            }
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;

}

}]);
```

**Directive Link Function**

```
app.directive('meetings', [ 'getCalendar', '$timeout', function(getCalendar, $timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/meetings.html',
    link: function(scope){
        getCalendar().then(function(events){
            scope.meetings = events;

            $timeout(function() {
                getCalendar();
            }, 60 * 1000 * 4);
        });

    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: try using `if` to check if `gapi` is defined

Comment: @CodeBean I said in my question that 'When I log "gapi" in my console I can see the "auth" object property.' gapi is defined but for some reason auth is undefined even though I can see it listed as an object property for gapi.

Comment: it might be possible that your object is not loaded when you try to use it . Normally happens when you use asynchronous calls with $q service. Happened to me couple of times when I tried to use a variable which was initialized inside then() section which was executing later on. But when i was debugging, the value was already set (because when my breakpoint reached, the then() was already called)

Comment: Thanks @Ammar. I added a timeout to my directive link function that calls the service and now it's working. Do you know another workaround for this? Or is this the most efficient way? Should I be using the Google API angular dependency instead?

Comment: Haven't used the google api but the timeout doesn't appear to be elegant solution, its prone to break if your server takes longer than the timeout. I guess google api should have ability to register your function as listener when the results are returned. after quick googling i found one guy using Google Api in angular here: https://github.com/gaslight/letsgitlunch/blob/master/controllers.js